# How do I pass in an element's ID and a string to my function using on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

The `OnChangeListener` has to take in the element's `ID` that fires it and also must pass in a string (that will be hard-coded in). This isn't working as I've learned that e is actually the event, not the `select` element. However, I don't know how to retrieve the ID this way. This script is supposed to attach this event handler to all select elements that meet the selector's criteria.

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-controltype=dropdown]', function (e) {
    OnChangeListener($(e).attr('id'), 'Dashboard.aspx/GetFilterDataCallBack');
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$(document).on('change', {senderId:$(this).attr('id'), callBack:'Dashboard.aspx/GetFilterDataCallBack' }, '[data-controltype=dropdown]', OnChangeListener});
```

That doesn't appear to be working either.

**Edit: this is in a `<script>` tag in my page.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just need to get the ID of the element that the event 'change' was fired against, you can use `$(this)` instead of `$(e)`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy your name cracks me up. My last 3 weeks I've probably said that 1000x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$(document).on('change', '[data-controltype=dropdown]', function (e) {
    OnChangeListener($(e).attr('id'), 'Dashboard.aspx/GetFilterDataCallBack');
});`
`e` refers to the event. To get the triggering element use

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-controltype=dropdown]', function (e) {
    OnChangeListener(this.id, 'Dashboard.aspx/GetFilterDataCallBack');
});
```

Comment: I always did $(this).attr('id').  I'll be using this.id from now on, though.  Never thought of it before, but it's pretty obvious.